# Интерпретатор JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, v8

Объясните пожалуйста подробно, что происходит в этом коде с точки зрения инетерпретатора.

```
let f = function(x) {
    console.log(x)
}

(function() {
    console.log(f)
    f(1)
}())
```

Мои размышления: Переменная f поднимается вверх и равна undefined, после она инициализируется ссылкой на объект функции из выражения определения функции, далее мы видим скобки, значит внутри выражение, а не инструкция, возвращается функция, после чего через оператор () она вызывается.

Ошибка: Cannot access 'f' before initialization

Я понимаю, что по всей видимости здесь происходит подъем этого замыкания, но я не понимаю зачем и почему.

Объясните пожалуйста :)

Comment: По моему, над тобой кто то пошутил, потому что тут нужно поставить точку с запятой.

Comment: Действительно, вот же дурачек. Я думал здесь все сложнее, ход мыслей вообще верен у меня?